# Order of results in MongoDB with $in?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

I'm searching an array using `$in`, what order will the results be returned in with no sorting specified? I'd like for them to be returned in the order of the array I search.

Comment: Could you provide an example to explain your question.  It's hard for a newbie like me to understand your question and therefore the answer without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: if you are searching with no sort order specified there is no guaranteed ordering of results.

Additionally, it isn't possible to sort by an array (even less so if you want to sort an array by an array as described).  A [sort()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D) uses logical comparison to determine ascending or descending order based on a field within your result documents.

You would have to implement any desired custom sorting logic in your own application code.

A useful approach might be to take advantage of the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2 .. in particular, the ability to [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_unwind) an array into a stream of documents.

For example, setting up test data as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac93fb50571321b2f932a"), "a" : [ 1, 2, 4 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac946b50571321b2f932b"), "a" : [ 5, 4, 9 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac94eb50571321b2f932c"), "a" : [ 2, 1, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac954b50571321b2f932d"), "a" : [ 7, 3, 9 ] }
```

An `$in` search on [2,3] would result in the matching documents:

```
> db.matches.find({'a': { $in: [2,3]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac93fb50571321b2f932a"), "a" : [ 1, 2, 4 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac94eb50571321b2f932c"), "a" : [ 2, 1, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504ac954b50571321b2f932d"), "a" : [ 7, 3, 9 ] }
```

With the aggregation framework you could `$match` the same documents and then manipulate the results to achieve some basic sorting: `$unwind` the arrays, `$sort` them, and then `$group` these back into a result:

```
db.matches.aggregate(
  { $match : {
       a: { $in: [2,3] }
  }},
  { $unwind : "$a" },
  { $sort: {
      "a": -1
  }},
  { $group : {
      _id: '$_id',
      a: { $addToSet: "$a" }
  }}
)
```

So in this example, the documents with matching arrays are now sorted in ascending order for the array values:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("504ac94eb50571321b2f932c"),
            "a" : [ 1, 2, 3]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("504ac93fb50571321b2f932a"),
            "a" : [ 1, 2, 4 ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("504ac954b50571321b2f932d"),
            "a" : [ 3, 7, 9 ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: this just not possible.