# mongodb - looking for select query similar to mysql's "id in(1,2,3,4)"

Tags: mysql, mongodb, search

One of the most common queries I use with mysql is:

```
select * from database where id in(1,5,3,2,4) order by field(id,1,5,3,2,4)
```

On a new project I'm using MongoDB, is there a similar query I can use? We use a separate search engine for actual searching and returns a list of ID's in a specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent MongoDB query would be:

```
db.collection.find({id: $in: [1,2,3,4,5]}).sort({id: 1})
```

But if you wanted to customize the `id` order beyond pure ascending you'd have to use the aggregation framework.

Comment: Ah shoot, should have mentioned the id order is not ascending/descending, updated my original question.

Comment: @Joe See Stennie's answer to this similar questions for the details on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12328099/1259510